# Cannot install older versions of tensorflow: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.9.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I need to install older versions of tensorflow to get the deepface library to work properly, however whenever I run pip install tensorflow==1.9.0, I get: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.9.0 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0)`

Anyone else run into this issue/know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I ran into the same issue. The reason behind it is because you are probably using python  version 3.8 or higher. Tensorflow does not support 3.8 version of python or higher.

Comment: `tensorflow==1.9.0` can only be installed with Python 2.7 / 3.3 / 3.4 / 3.5 / 3.6, so downgrade Python to 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

You can install TensorFlow 1.9.0 with the following Python versions: 2.7 and 3.4 to 3.6.